# Mockito-core 2.7.19 and CGLIB

Tags: maven, mockito, junit4, cglib, catch-exception

I am running a test that uses google's catch-exception. 
I am using mockito-core version 2.7.19, catch-exception version 1.2.0 and junit 4.12.

When I use the following statement in a test: 
@RunWith(org.mockito.junit.MockitoJunnitRunner.class) 
....

```
//given
don't care.

//when
 catchException()

//then

 don't care
```

I'd got this:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mockito/cglib/proxy/MethodInterceptor
    at xxxx.NullIfAnotherFieldDoesntHaveValueValidatorTest.shouldTrowsRuntimeExceptionInCaseOfNoSuchMethodException(NullIfAnotherFieldDoesntHaveValueValidatorTest.java:203)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:68)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:74)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:39)
    at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mockito.cglib.proxy.MethodInterceptor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 29 more
```

I know cgilib was replaced but it seems mockito itself is looking for cgilib. I also tried mockito-cgilib but it seems to not have a maven release.
I would appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance,

Marcelo

Answer (score 1):

Mockito 2+ does no longer use cglib. I assume that you are having two versions of the library on the class path. Those versions are not compatible.

Comment: No I am not, I also remembered that catch-exception does not work with "Spy" annotation  and this object uses Spy so this might be the problem. Changing to "Rule"-based exception catcher solved the problem.

Comment: You most definetly have. Mockito 2 does not include the class that shows up in your stack trace.